# How to convert "apply" in this kotlin code to java?

Tags: java, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to convert this kotlin code to java to set the itemAnimator for a recylcer view

```
cardStackView.itemAnimator.apply {
        if (this is DefaultItemAnimator) {
            supportsChangeAnimations = false
        }
    }
```

So far i have come up with something like this:

```
cardStackView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator(){

             @Override
             public void setSupportsChangeAnimations(boolean supportsChangeAnimations) {
                                         super.setSupportsChangeAnimations(supportsChangeAnimations);

                   }
             }
    );
```

Comment: Do you understand what `apply` does? What you have come up with is very different from the kotlin code...

Comment: I looked it up [here](https://www.journaldev.com/19467/kotlin-let-run-also-apply-with) . But i was still facing error, so I somehow ended up with the above code after a lot of tinkering. I know it is absolutely wrong, can you please help me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, someone has just answered. Does their answer work?

Comment: Yes it does work @Swee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = cardStackView.getItemAnimator();
        if (itemAnimator instanceof DefaultItemAnimator) {
            DefaultItemAnimator di = (DefaultItemAnimator) itemAnimator;
            di.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }
```